# vista can not allow me to insert or select record msaccess from database when i login from user not admin

Tags: c#

i have little problem in using my application application having msaccess database if i install it on xp i can easily insert or select record from database but if i install it on vista. i can't access my msaccess database. if i login as admin it works fine but if i login as user i cant insert or select any record from my msaccess database from application please tell me what should i do.

Comment: where is this database/application located? folder path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it is a file security problem - In Windows Vista, UAC disallows writes to various directories and instead, redirects them to the virtual store directory.

You cam either place the database in the recommended location under appdata in the user's folder, or, put the file in a general place that every user can write to - such as the programdata folder - or lastly, you can "hack" it together by right clicking the access file and going to "Properties > Security" and giving either the individual user or a group such as "everyone" full/write access to the file.

Comment: i want to give access to everyone can i do it from c#